# python check if function accepts **kwargs

Tags: python

is there a way to check if a function accepts **kwargs before calling it e.g.

```
def FuncA(**kwargs):
    print 'ok'

def FuncB(id = None):
    print 'ok'

def FuncC():
    print 'ok'

args = {'id': '1'}

FuncA(**args)
FuncB(**args)
FuncC(**args)
```

When I run this FuncA and FuncB would be okay but FuncC errors with `got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'` as it doesn't accept any arguments

Comment: If it's that important whether the function accepts kwargs, why don't you already know? If it isn't particularly important, then just try, as suggested.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
try:
    f(**kwargs)
except TypeError:
    #do stuff
```

It's [easier to ask forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-EAFP).

Comment: "It is easier to ask for forgiveness than permission".. +1

Comment: Yep, it should, fixed. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, no. This will work with _any_ non-built-in function provided that you craft `**kwargs` right. `def foo(x): return x` then `foo(**{'x':1})`.

Comment: @9000: sure, but in these cases we don't generally care - the question is *really* "can I successfully call the function with the particular arguments I propose to pass to it?".

Comment: @9000, @Karl: yes; Python is fluid about arguments and will try to match up the arguments a function receives with the arguments that it wants. It would be harder, and fragile, to determine whether the function was actually _defined_ with kwargs.

Comment: @katrielalex: Not tricky at all for pure Python functions; nearly impossible for built-ins and C extension functions. (I spent too much time working exactly on this, and, alas, the docstring turns out to be the most reliable source in such cases.)

Comment: @9000: I think there are probably lots of nasty corner cases where you could do silly dynamic things to functions, although I agree that in general `inspect` will do what you want. But it's still sort of a hack IMO.

Comment: @katrielalex: `inspect` is at least a documented piece of Python stdlib, and there's no problem to actually look at function's AST and find out things about arguments (`ast` is also a part of stdlib). The 'hack' is your solution: quick, concise, and gets work done when you're lucky :)

Comment: you can do it in this funky mannar: def test(**kwargs) .... if '**kwargs' in help(test):  do stuff

Comment: This gets the job done, but I can't help but feel like its dangerous. If your function throws a `TypeError` anywhere in the code, its impossible to know from this snippet whether the `TypeError` is from passing invalid `kwargs` or from an error in your logic.

Comment: The problem with this solution is you can't distinguish an "Argument Binding" TypeError from a TypeError thrown by f. Better to use [`inspect.Signature.bind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature.bind)

Comment: What if `f` deletes your operating system?

Comment: This solution should not the the accepted answer. To run a function when only an inspection of the function is required is not the intention of the user question. Running the function could be dangerous and is certainly unintended.

Comment: What if the argument format [comes from an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064101/how-to-check-what-arguments-an-event-provides-in-python), where the event format is unknown? (Then `inspect` doesn't seem to work.)

Answer (score 16):

```
def foo(a, b, **kwargs):
  pass

import inspect
args, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(foo)
assert(varkw=='kwargs')
```

This only works for Python functions. Functions defined in C extensions (and built-ins) may be tricky and sometimes interpret their arguments in quite creative ways. There's no way to reliably detect which arguments such functions expect. Refer to function's docstring and other human-readable documentation.

Comment: If you're using inspection the name of the keyword argument is irrelevant and you don't check for a named argument. `varkw is not None or 'id' in args` would be how it should look like.

Comment: Yes, the name is irrelevant. The _presence_ is relevant. Try inspecting a function without a `**kwarg`; `varkw` will be `None`. I suppose that you check the code samples using an actual interpreter.

Comment: If only the presence is irrelevant, why are you giving an example checking for the name?

Comment: Good point. I checked the name to show the connection with function definition, but this is not necessary in `**kwargs` case; `assert(varkw is not None)` would be enough.

Comment: EAFP is great for a number of things, but in the case where you are running a function "blindly" without knowing its exact signature without inspection, this answer is much more reliable.

Comment: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated since Python 3.0, use inspect.signature() or inspect.getfullargspec() instead

Answer (score 7):

Seeing that there are a multitude of different answers in this thread, I thought I would give my two cents, using `inspect.signature()`.

Suppose you have this method:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
```

You can test if `**kwargs` are in this method's signature:

```
import inspect

sig = inspect.signature(foo)
params = sig.parameters.values()
has_kwargs = any([True for p in params if p.kind == p.VAR_KEYWORD])
```

### More

Getting the parameters in which a method takes is also possible:

```
import inspect

sig = inspect.signature(foo)
params = sig.parameters.values()
for param in params:
    print(param.kind)
```

You can also store them in a variable like so:

```
kinds = [param.kind for param in params]

# [<_ParameterKind.VAR_KEYWORD: 4>]
```

Other than just keyword arguments, there are 5 parameter kinds in total, which are as follows:

```py
POSITIONAL_ONLY        # parameters must be positional

POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD  # parameters can be positional or keyworded (default)

VAR_POSITIONAL         # *args

KEYWORD_ONLY           # parameters must be keyworded 

VAR_KEYWORD            # **kwargs
```

Descriptions in the official documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter.kind).

### Examples

`POSITIONAL_ONLY`

```
def foo(a, /): 
# the '/' enforces that all preceding parameters must be positional

foo(1) # valid
foo(a=1) #invalid
```

---

`POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD`

```
def foo(a):
# 'a' can be passed via position or keyword
# this is the default and most common parameter kind
```

---

`VAR_POSITIONAL`

```
def foo(*args):
```

---

`KEYWORD_ONLY`

```
def foo(*, a):
# the '*' enforces that all following parameters must by keyworded

foo(a=1) # valid
foo(1) # invalid
```

---

`VAR_KEYWORD`

```
def foo(**kwargs):
```

Answer (score 6):

`func` is the function in question.

with python2, it's:

```
inspect.getargspec(func).keywords is not None
```

python3 is a bit tricker, following https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/ the `kind` of parameter must be `VAR_KEYWORD`

> Parameter.VAR_KEYWORD - a dict of keyword arguments that aren't bound to any other parameter. This corresponds to a "**kwargs" parameter in a Python function definition.

```
any(param for param in inspect.signature(func).parameters.values() if param.kind == param.VAR_KEYWORD)
```

Answer (score 6):

For python > 3 you should to use [inspect.getfullargspec](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec).

```py
import inspect

def foo(**bar):
    pass

arg_spec = inspect.getfullargspec(foo)
assert arg_spec.varkw and arg_spec.varkw == 'bar'
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you want to check whether the function receives an 'id' keyword argument. You can't really do that by inspection because the function might not be a normal function, or you might have a situation like that:

```
def f(*args, **kwargs):
    return h(*args, **kwargs)

g = lambda *a, **kw: h(*a, **kw)

def h(arg1=0, arg2=2):
    pass
```

`f(id=3)` still fails

Catching `TypeError` as suggested is the best way to do that, but you can't really figure out what caused the `TypeError`. For example, this would still raise a `TypeError`:

```
def f(id=None):
     return "%d" % id

f(**{'id': '5'})
```

And that might be an error that you want to debug. And if you're doing the check to avoid some side effects of the function, they might still be present if you catch it. For example:

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self): self._items = set([1,2,3])
   def f(self, id): return self._items.pop() + id

a = A()
a.f(**{'id': '5'})
```

My suggestion is to try to identify the functions by another mechanism. For example, pass objects with methods instead of functions, and call only the objects that have a specific method. Or add a flag to the object or the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html
you should be able to test for use of `**kwargs` using `co_flags`:

```
>>> def blah(a, b, kwargs):
...     pass

>>> def blah2(a, b, **kwargs):
...     pass

>>> (blah.func_code.co_flags & 0x08) != 0
False
>>> (blah2.func_code.co_flags & 0x08) != 0
True
```

Though, as noted in the reference this may change in the future, so I would definitely advise to be extra careful. Definitely add some unit tests to check this feature is still in place.

Comment: I see nothing in the reference saying this may change in the future, or even that it's implementation specific. The closest thing to a warning note that I see is: "Other bits in co_flags are reserved for internal use."